# Declaring attributes when creating classes in Java

Tags: java, oop, attributes

Sometimes there are attributes that come about as a result of a `mathematical` operation. When declaring those attributes does one write the mathematical operation? For example, I need to write a `class` representing a `moment in time` with an attribute that has the amount of seconds since midnight for that moment in time. Would I declare it as such:

```
private long _secFromMid;?
```

Or would I need to declare it as

```
private long _secFromMid = ((_hour*60*60) + (_minute*60) + _second);?
```

Do we ever have mathematical operations when declaring `attributes`?

Comment: You can simply try doing that right ?

Comment: use camelCase... And yes, you can initialize it with math expressions. If you are doing that, then mark the field as `final` and `transient`

Comment: Usually the variables initializing at class definition considered as static (class) variables  .if you want to change the formula in future you can keep it as it is or otherwise use "final" block to declared as a constant .

Comment: I assume `_hour` etc. are mutable, so you'll need to update `_secFromMid` every time a value is set. Therefor your initialization will not suffice.

Comment: Why not use a getter instance method that returns that calculation instead of an instance variable?

Comment: @rb612 I do have to write a getter method that returns that attribute as a result of the calculation. But the class also has an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can do any computations in initialization. Java compiler is smart enough to put things in order.

The only restriction is that you can only use another property if it has alread been declared.

See this [working example](https://ideone.com/hSeeIC).

```
class Test
{
    private String foo = "foo";
    private String fooBar = foo + "bar";
    private int x = 10;
    private int y = x * 10;
    private MyInt my = new MyInt(5);
    private int z = x * my.get();

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        System.out.println(t.foo);
        System.out.println(t.fooBar);
        System.out.println(t.x);
        System.out.println(t.y);
        System.out.println(t.z);
    }
}
```

For example, if I changed the code to this:

```
class Test
{
    private String fooBar = foo + "bar"; // inverted here
    private String foo = "foo";
    private int x = 10;
    private int y = x * 10;
    private MyInt my = new MyInt(5);
    private int z = x * my.get();

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        System.out.println(t.foo);
        System.out.println(t.fooBar);
        System.out.println(t.x);
        System.out.println(t.y);
        System.out.println(t.z);
    }
}
```

This will cause a compilation error:

> ```
> Compilation error time: 0.1 memory: 320576 signal:0
> Main.java:19: error: illegal forward reference
>     private String fooBar = foo + "bar";
>                             ^
> 1 error
> ```